# How to dynamically define a path using a file prefix within a directory?

Tags: bash, shell

I wrote a bash script that first takes a `projectRoot` from a processor.properties file. Then creates a `metricsRoot`, removes a directory that contains matrics data (`metricsDir`) and rewrites the data in the `metricsDir`.

Now I want to define the /data dir name dynamically depending on a prefix of files within the directory. For example there may be files like `common.mertics1.csv` in the `metricsDir`. So I need to take the prefix before the dot (`common` in this case). And the `metricsDir` should look like `metricsDir=$metricsRoot/$metricsPrefix`.

How can I achieve this within the bash script?

```
#!/bin/bash

file="/configs/processor.properties"
projectRoot=$(grep -Po '(?<=projectRoot=).+$' "$file")

abspath=`dirname "$(cd "${0%/*}" 2>/dev/null; echo "$PWD"/"${0##*/}")"`
metricsRoot=$projectRoot/metrics
metricsDir=$metricsRoot/data

whoami=`whoami`

if [ "x${whoami}" != "xoozie" ] ; then
    echo "ERROR: You need to be an oozie user"
    exit 127
fi

hadoop fs -mkdir $metricsRoot
hadoop fs -rm -r $metricsDir
hadoop fs -put $abspath $metricsDir
```

Comment: Can you add example catalog tree? It's hard to deduce what do you want to achieve.

Comment: @JUSHJUSH the files are originally locaded in a classpath: `/resources/metrics/data/common.mertics1.csv`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to get the prefix of the first file in the `$abspath` you could use something like this:-

```
filenames=`ls "$abspath"/*.csv`

for filename in $filenames
do
    filename="${filename%%.*}"
    metricsPrefix="${filename##*/}"
    break
done

echo $metricsPrefix
```

You should test to see if `$metricsPrefix` actually contains anything before you use it though.

Comment: Actually I want to take the prefix of a first file in the directory if it exists

Comment: OK, I've edited the answer to get the prefix of the first file